# Layers with GDI+

Tags: c++, gdi+, bitmap

I'm thinking of creating a drawing program with layers, and using GDI+ to display them. I want to use GDI+ because it supports transparency.

The thing is, drawing lines to the DC is very fast, but drawing directly to a bitmap is very slow. It is only fast if you lock the bits and start setting pixels. Can I draw to multiple DC's in my WM_PAINT event, then just do DrawBitmap for each layer to the MemDC? What's the best way of going about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDI+ is certainly fast enough for a drawing program.  I use it (from C#) for high-speed animation (>30 fps).

It appears that you want to be able to manipulate individual pixels.  This is *very* fast with LockBits, and although it's slightly clunky to use in C# (requiring a pointer and the `unsafe` tag), it doesn't seem like it would be as difficult in C++.

You probably don't want to copy from multiple layers directly to your control surface inside a paint event.  Instead, this rendering should be done to an off-screen buffer (B1).  After B1 is drawn with all copying/drawing operations completed, copy it to a second off-screen buffer (B2) and then invalidate/refresh your control surface.  In the control's paint event, you copy from B2 to the visible surface.

You don't want to draw directly on the visible surface with a multi-step drawing operation, since a form of flickering will result (sometimes the screen will repaint itself while your code is only partway through a multi-step operation, so the user sees an occasional half-finished frame).

You can render to a single off-screen buffer, and copy from it to the visible surface in the paint event.  The main complication here is that you have to deal in some way with "stray" paint events, i.e. events not caused by your intentionally invalidating the control but by something else (like a user dragging another window over yours).  If you copy from the off-screen buffer to the surface and the buffer is only halfway-drawn, you'll get flicker.  If you block in the paint event until the buffer drawing is completed, you'll see "form trails" on your control, which looks even worse.

The solution is the double-buffered approach described above.  Stray (or non-stray ones when you invalidate) paint events will copy from B2, which is always fully-rendered and up-to-date - thus no flicker.  Double-buffering does use more memory, but in a drawing program that has multiple layers anyway, this isn't a big deal.